# Is there any way to cancel a flag?

Tags: feature-request, flagging

I flagged a post (which I thought looked like a comment), then the person re-edited it to be an answer. How can I cancel the flag?

Comment: This question has been asked on meta.SO and was closed as a dupe (doesn't look like one to me, though). http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90142/feature-request-ability-to-edit-delete-flags

Comment: @HodofHod: That MSO question is not exactly this one, either.

Comment: @msh210 If you read the update to it, you will see that mentions Shmuels (nearly) exact scenario.

Comment: @HodofHod, er, yes, so it does. `:-)` Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is **no way** to take back a flag.

Once you flag you have to live with it (it seems).

[See related meta.SO Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87660/155556)